# Properly formatted message for APNs

Tags: pubnub

I checked everything that i found about the topic on GitHub and in the tutorials, but couldn't find the right solution.

As I read in the Mobile Push Gateway [tut](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/objective-c/iOS/tutorial/apple-push-notification.html), I can send a string or something like this:

```
{
      "aps" : {
        "alert": "If you are reading this, you should have just received an alert.",
        "badge": 9,
        "sound": "bingbong.aiff"
      }
}
```

So I've tried to send it as `NSString`, `NSDictionary` and `NSData`, but I couldn't receive it.

The solutions I tried:

a,

```
NSString *apns = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello world."];
[PubNub sendMessage: apns toChannel:channel_3];
```

b,

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
                       @"aps" : @{ @"alert" : @"new push" }
                       };
[PubNub sendMessage: dict toChannel:channel_3];
```

c,

```
// create the apns dictionary
NSString *apns = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello world."];
NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"aps" : @{ @"alert" : apns } };


//create the json
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];

 NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 [PubNub sendMessage: jsonString toChannel:channel_3];
```

d,

```
NSString *apns = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello world."];
NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"aps" : @{ @"alert" : apns } };


//create the json
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];


[PubNub sendMessage: jsonData toChannel:channel_3];
```

e,

```
NSDictionary *pushPub = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
pushPub = @{ @"alert": someString} ;
NSMutableDictionary *fullPush = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[fullPush setObject:pusPub forKey:@"aps"];
[PubNub sendMessage: jsonData toChannel:channel_3];
```

I have no more ideas what could I try apart from these. Otherwise I received the welcome message, so it was implemented properly.

I'm testing it on two iPhones and using this code in my AppDelegate (same as the setup guide verison).

```
// #5 Process received push notification
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    NSLog(@"PUSH TEST LOG");
    NSString *message = nil;
    id alert = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    if ([alert isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        message = alert;
    } else if ([alert isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        message = [alert objectForKey:@"alert"];
    }
    if (alert) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:message
                                                            message:message  delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks PubNub!"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Send Me More!", nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

And I use this in my `ViewController`'s 'viewDidLoad'

```
 [[PNObservationCenter defaultCenter] addClientConnectionStateObserver:self withCallbackBlock:^(NSString *origin, BOOL connected, PNError *connectionError){

        if (connected)
        {
            NSLog(@"OBSERVER: Successful Connection!");

            // Subscribe on connect
            [PubNub subscribeOnChannels:channels];


            // #3 Define AppDelegate
            AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

            // #4 Pass the deviceToken from the Delegate
            deviceToken = appDelegate.dToken;

            // #5 Double check we've passed the token properly
            NSLog(@"Device token received: %@", deviceToken);

            // #6 If we have the device token, enable apns for our channel if it isn't already enabled.
            if (deviceToken) {

                // APNS enabled already?
                [PubNub requestPushNotificationEnabledChannelsForDevicePushToken:deviceToken
                                                     withCompletionHandlingBlock:^(NSArray *channels, PNError *error){
                                                         if (channels.count == 0 )
                                                         {
                                                             NSLog(@"BLOCK: requestPushNotificationEnabledChannelsForDevicePushToken: Channel: %@ , Error %@",channels,error);

                                                             // Enable APNS on this Channel with deviceToken
                                                             [PubNub enablePushNotificationsOnChannel:myPushChannel
                                                                                  withDevicePushToken:deviceToken
                                                                           andCompletionHandlingBlock:^(NSArray *channel, PNError *error){
                                                                               NSLog(@"BLOCK: enablePushNotificationsOnChannel: %@ , Error %@",channel,error);
                                                                           }];
                                                         }
                                                     }];
            }
        }
        else if (!connected || connectionError != nil )
        {
            NSLog(@"OBSERVER: Error %@, Connection Failed!", connectionError.localizedDescription);
        }

    }];
```

I saw this log in the console `OBSERVER: Error %@, Connection Failed!"`, however I also had this within the same session `PubNub client successfully subscribed on channels: desiredChannels` so I think the client can subscribe to the channel which receives the push messages and the problem is with my messages. Possibly somebody could show me a right example, that how can I do it in obj-c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, that something else caused my problem, so one of my implementation was right.

Here is a proper dictionary, that you can send via PubNub as a push message.

```
NSDictionary *myPushMessage = @{ @"aps" : @{ @"alert" : @"Push notification content" } };

PNChannel *pushReceiver = [PNChannel channelWithName:recevierChannel shouldObservePresence:NO];

[PubNub sendMessage: myPushMessage toChannel:pushReceiver];
```

If you followed the Mobile Push Gateway [tutorial](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/objective-c/iOS/tutorial/apple-push-notification.html) it must work perfectly.

Comment: If you satisfied with your response, accept it please.